# C# ASP.NET Slider JavaScript react differently in HTML page and ASPX Web Site

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

needed help again,
I found some template online which I can use, I tried to copy it and put inside my html, it works, however the slider had some problem.

If its on .HTML format, the Slider works perfectly fine like this, it reaches until the end of conversation.

[image]

But if its in the .ASPX file, it will looks like this

[image]

It slides out of the container, does anyone know what cause the problem?

Btw, the code is exactly the same, same css, bootstrap and JS
Thanks

Comment: Without being able to see the code or the actual pages in the browser probably not. What's different in the pages? Different style sheets. Looks like your .aspx page has an extra button.

Comment: Hi, the code is exactly the same. The slight difference is that ASPX has runat server

Comment: Is that runat causing the element to have a different name or the elements children to have a different name? What if you remove that?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderHiggins
I found the problem, if I remove the    <form id="form1" runat="server">
then it will work properly, do you know what causes that? Thanks

Comment: In my answer I outlined the reasons it will stop working as well as ways to address the issue. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your ASPX page when you apply the `runat=server` can cause the id of your control to change in the browser.

For example on a regular html generic control you may have:

```
<input id='mybutton' type='button' value='Go' />
```

When you apply the `runat=server` to a control that is nested inside of a parent control, such as a master page or a user control the ID that gets generated in the web browser can change:

For example, when using a master control, content is typically place in a content placeholder. If the above control was placed like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"><input id='mybutton' type='button' value='Go' runat='server' /> </asp:content>
```

The ASP.NET will render the control in the browser something like this:

```
<input id='MainContent_mybutton' type='button' value='Go' runat='server'  />
```

The name attribute of the control can also be changed.

This is by design so ASP.NET can keep track of your controls and make sure they are in the correct hierarchy of a pages control collection. The ID and name are also use to populate objects and raise event handlers for control methods.

You can override the changing of the id by setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the control, but take care that you don't end up with multiple controls with the same id.

You will need to make sure that the ID matches those set in any CSS or JavaScript. A common method to handle this is to leave the generated client id and reference it in JavaScript like this:

```
var mybuttonId = '<%= mybutton.ClientID %>';
```

You also need to be careful that any skins or themes you have set in your application don't override the default styles of your controls.

To fix your issue, compare the rendered normal HTML of your controls to those rendered by ASP.NET. The either address ASP.NET changing the ID/NAME/STYLE/CLASS attributes or update your JavaScript and CSS to use the names generated by your aspx page.